# помогите выдает ошибку Undefined offset: 2

Tags: php, laravel

у меня проверяется значение двух разных массивов и если они совпадают то они удаляются

```
for($i=0;$i<=max(array_keys($total_info_dec));$i++){
                $qwe=$total_info[$i]->user_id;

                $qwe3=$user_chek_dec_3[$i];//ошибка Undefined offset: 2

               if($qwe==$qwe3)
                   unset($total_info[$i]);


            }
```

Comment: Проверьте у себя, возможно  `$user_chek_dec_3` не является массивом или просто у него нет значения под ключём [2]. PS для сравнения двух массивов есть и оптимальные методы, как пример `array_diff_assoc `

Comment: там не так все просто  этой командой(array_diff_assoc ) не справится

Comment: Ну если там всё так сложно, всегда проверяйте есть ли данные с нужным ключом в `$user_chek_dec_3[$i]` и после продолжайте логику сравнения...

Answer (score 0):

`max(array_keys($total_info_dec));` это что то типа взять ключи и максимальный ключ. Короче не подходит, ибо может буть ключи типа `0,1,4,5,6,7` и for 7 раз пройдет. По этому `$i >= count($array)`. но пойдем дальше. Заменим `for` на `foreach` а лучше `array_filter` заюзаем

```
$result = array_filter($total_info, function ($e) use ($total_info_dec) {
    // далее просто ищем текущее значение в массиве dec если есть значит false 
    // и он не попадет в результат, если нет значит true 
    if (array_search($e, $total_info_dec) !== false) {
       return false;
    } else {
       return true;
    }

    // многие заметили что можно еще легче сделать тоесть вернуть результат выражения
    // return array_search($e, $total_info_dec) === false;
});
```

судя по вашему примеру и что цикл идет по одному массиву, потом берет значение из другого и сравнивает с третьим :-) Надо подниматься выше по коду и решать проблему в корне.